# Redis get first elements of many LIST keys

Tags: redis

Is there a way to get many list's (in various keys) first items?

so

```
K1 = [1,2,3,4]
K2 = [19, 24]

> XXXX K1, K2 ==> [1, 19]
```

and for nonexisting lists it should indicate somehow like:

```
K1 = [1,2,3,4]
K2 = [19, 24]

> XXXX K1, K3, K2 ==> [1, None, 19]
```

Let's say I have 2000 keys I need to update and I don't want to make 2000 queries. I also cannot get all 2000 full values because lists are long (let's say length of 500)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have make this number of queries, one for each List's key. The workflow can be optimized, however, with [pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) or a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval):

```
$ redis-cli RPUSH K2 19 24
(integer) 2
$ redis-cli RPUSH K1 1 2 3 4
(integer) 4
$ redis-cli --eval mlrange.lua K1 K3 K2
1) "1"
2) (nil)
3) "19"
$ cat mlrange.lua
local reply = {}
for _, key in ipairs(KEYS) do
    local elems = redis.call('LRANGE', key, 0, 0)
    if elems then
        reply[#reply+1] = elems[1]
    else
        reply[#reply+1] = false
    end
end
return reply
```